# My back text redirecting me to my index page is not working. (Beginner)

Tags: html, css

My goal is to get this back button to redirect me to my index.html  page. The redirect button is located on my about.html page. Whenever I click it, nothing happens. The button to direct me to my about page works, but this one doesn't. Any ideas on this issue?

HTML (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&family=IBM+Plex+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="nameText">
            <h1>Bleu Strnad</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="aspirationText">
            <h2>Programmer | Innovator | Computer Enthusiast </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="mainPFP1">
            <img src="img/mainPFP.PNG", width = "800px", height = "800", alt="programmer themed electronics and coffee">
        </div>
        
        <div class="AboutPG">
            <a href="about.html" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><u>About</u></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML (about.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abril+Fatface&family=IBM+Plex+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="BackBTN">
            <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><u>Back</u></a>
        </div>

        <div class="nameTextABT">
            <h1>Bleu Strnad</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="captionTextABT">
            <h1>About</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="aboutParagraph"> 
            <p>Bleu Strnad is an aspring computer scientist with a burning passions for 
                the subject. Growing up with a computer within sight indefinitely, he questioned how 
                it worked. Little did he know, there is a ever-growing massive industry
                based off this one machine. Attempting to answer these questions of his,
                 he is now studying vigorously to answer his call to this simple yet difficult, paradoxical industry. </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS (style.css)

```
.abril {
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
}

.serif {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Serif', serif;
}

.mainPFP1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 1400px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.nameText {
    font-family: "Abril Fatface", cursive;
    position: relative;
    font-size: larger;
    top: 550px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 1000px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.aspirationText {
    font-family: "IBM Plex Serif", serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10px;
    top: 525px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 1000px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.AboutPG{
    font-family: "IBM Plex Serif", serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17.5px;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0px;
    left: 1000px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: -285px;
}

.BackBTN {
    font-family: "Abril Fatface";
    position: relative;
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 2360px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.nameTextABT {
    font-family: "Abril Fatface", cursive;
    position: relative;
    font-size: larger;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: -55px;
}

.captionTextABT {
    font-family: "Abril Fatface", cursive;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.aboutParagraph
{
    font-family: "IBM Plex Serif", serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0px;
    left: 750px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    inline-size: 1000px; 
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Based on the code you have provided, your back button works exactly as expected. The problem (if there is one), lies outside of your above example.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I was thinking that two, I've been going over it. I edited the post and added my index.html file which has to be the one causing errors.

Comment: Hey, maybe ur index.html file is sotred in a different directory, maybe give a path to that directory as well, idk, but this coukd be an issue

Comment: also maybe check if u havent misspeelled the index.html file coz the name needs to match

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.